# Is my usage of blockquote elements acceptable from an accessibility perspective?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, user-experience, screen-readers

I have an easy route to output some markup I can take which results in:

```
<blockquote>The quote</blockquote>
<blockquote>The quotee</blockquote>
```

For example (1):

```
<blockquote>The secret of getting ahead is getting started.</blockquote>
<blockquote>- Mark Twain</blockquote>
```

That feels a bit icky to me, as though the contents of a blockquote should all be self-contained. And also that in doing this, I might trigger some less-than-desirable result with assistive technologies, such as screen readers, relying on semantic markup.

If it were self-contained, that would then require additional markup to reliably style the quotee differently from the quote with CSS, for example (2):

```
<blockquote>
  The secret of getting ahead is getting started.
  <span>- Mark Twain</span>
</blockquote>
```

All feelings about encapsulation aside, does anyone know if there is a perceptible difference in how those different approaches are presented to users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the content of `<cite>` is part of the quote itself it should not live within the `<blockquote>`, only the quotation should be within.

As [detailed in the html5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) for blockquotes the correct markup in this situation would be to use `<figure>` to group the quote and author. From the spec:

> …a blockquote element is used in conjunction with a figure element and its figcaption to clearly relate a quote to its attribution (which is not part of the quote and therefore doesn't belong inside the blockquote itself)

Do, given your example the ideal markup pattern would be:

```
<figure>
    <blockquote>
        <p>The secret of getting ahead is getting started.</p> 
    </blockquote>
    <figcaption>Mark Twain</figcaption>
</figure>
```

`<cite>` would be used to point to the actual *source* of that quote.

Comment: This is the answer I needed back then, hopefully helpful to someone now too - definitely still relevant.

Comment: and I needed the answer again just now, thanks twice :D

Answer (score 2):

Your last example is best, since the it is grouped, but use the `cite` as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite:

```css
cite:before {
 content: '- ';
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
    The secret of getting ahead is getting started.
    <cite>Mark Twain</cite>
</blockquote>
```

Just style cite:

Comment: Interesting, from a content ownership perspective rather than solely an accessibility perspective? I hadn't really considered that as a reason. I'd still like to know if there is an end-user perceptible difference between the solutions however.

Comment: There is a little difference on how the information is presented, but really not that much. As human beings we are smart enough to distinguish the quote from its author.
However, I encourage you to use the most semantically correct solution in any case. Tomorrow the difference might become more significant.

Comment: Yeah, fair call QuentinC, ok, accepting the above as the correct enough answer. If anyone has any data on what users do get presented with, for example a screenreader reading out "quote begins: The secret of getting ahead is getting started. quote ends. quote begins Mark Twain. quote ends." or things like that, please do add them to this question as I'm still interested in knowing.

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. Unless the cite is part of the content of the quote itself it should not be within the blockquote element.